# How can I implement this widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to implement this overlay page (it's an iOS design style) but I can't found any resources to do it with Flutter, Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet), with GestureDector (swipe left and right) to swith pages:

```
showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Container(),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, All I want is the name of the sheet (Modal Bottom Sheet)